# What is difference between class A:public virtual B and class A:public B

Tags: c++, virtual, multiple-inheritance

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class base
{
    public:
      virtual void f(){}
};

class middle1:public base
{};

class middle2:public base
{};

class derive:public middle1,public middle2
{};



int main()
{
    derive* pd=new derive();
    pd->f();
    return 0;
}
```

I know that virtual solves this problem, but how? 
Can we always write public virtual for safety, even we don't have multiple inheritance.

Comment: virtual tells compiler that take copy of methods and member variables from base not from middle2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each instance of `derive` has a `middle1` base class sub-object and a `middle2` base class sub-object.

If the inheritance is non-virtual, then the `middle1` base class sub-object has a `base` base class subobject, *and* the `middle2` base class sub-object also has a `base` base class sub-object. Hence, each instance of `derive` has two `base` sub-objects, and the call `pd->f()` is ambiguous -- which of the `base` objects do you want to call `f()` on?

Making the inheritance virtual means that `middle1` and `middle2` will share a single `base` sub-object of `derive`. This removes the ambiguity -- there is only one `base` object that `f()` could be called on.

> Can we always write public virtual for safety

Not necessarily. There may be inheritance hierarchies in which you don't *want* `middle1` and `middle2` to share a public `base` sub-object. You could probably argue that in such cases, you shouldn't be writing a class `derive` that inherits from both, but if you do end up with that situation then the workaround would be to do either:

```
static_cast<middle1*>(pd)->f();
pd->middle1::f();
```

to specify that you want to call `f` on the `middle1` base class sub-object, or

```
static_cast<middle2*>(pd)->f();
pd->middle2::f();
```

to specify `middle2`.

Answer (score 1):

> **I know that virtual solves this problem, but how?**

`virtual` keywords solves the problem by making only one top order base class subobject to be present in the inheritance hierarchy. Without it each parent class `middle1` & `middle2` have their own copy of the `base` class thus resulting in ambiguity.

> **Can we always write public virtual for safety, even we don't have multiple inheritance.**

There is no reason to use `virtual` inheritance if you don't have multiple inheritance. Multiple inheritance is the purpose for concept of virtual inheritance to exist.

Answer (score 1):

Virtual base classes implement an additional indirection level in order to solve the diamond problem (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5179854/virtual-inheritance-in-c)).

If you always use virtual inheritance, you will always suffer the performance penalty resulting from that additional indirection level.

Therefore, I would suggest you only use virtual inheritance when you have to.